# Error with msp when try to Launch Peers with Fabric-ca

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Currently, I follow the Fabric CA Operation Guide -> https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html# with Fabric-ca-1.4.7.

But When I try to launch a peer with docker (peer1-org1) Some errors occurs like :
`ERRO 030 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo` 
or
 `ERRO 02f Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/msp: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

When I followed the guide some actions of folder's population didn't happen correctly, like on -> Enroll Orderer Org’s CA Admin :
`/tmp/hyperledger/org0/ca/admin` nothing happened in, it's on an another folder (.fabric-ca-client) or again on msp folders, for all keystore and cacerts are on the same folder (.fabric-ca-client).

To arrived to the step to launch a peer, I had to do some tricks like search where is the file I need, because they are not in the normal folder or modify the default cmd of Fabric-ca-client.
My goal is just to start a default network, like on tutorial but with Fabric-ca.

So, what goes wrong on my step ?

Before to launch a peer no error occurred.

Comment: Please make sure that you are setting up the required environment variables correctly as put up in the document guide (the link that you are using) before every enrollment call.

Comment: The environment variables was the concern, it must have been an authorization problem. Thank you so much. I now advance in the guide to configtxgen. Attention for others, when Enroll Org0’s Admin: enroll orderer-org0-admin:ordererAdminPW does not exist, replace it by admin-org0:org0adminpw (see Enroll Orderer Org’s CA Admin and if you have not modified it like me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start a simple network using Fabric CA, you can try to run [test-network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/test-network) of fabric-samples. Using the command: `./network.sh up createChannel -ca`. Go through line by line in **network.sh** shell script and you will understand how to use Fabric CA easily and friendly.

Comment: The tutorial goes further than I expected the first time i used, with `-ca`, it's a good point. I play with the sample now, especially since I encountered another error when initiating the chaincode with the guide.